# RxJava, good use case of flatmap

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm new to RxJava, often got confused by flatMap function. According to the [doc](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html), flatmap `transform the items emitted by an Observable into Observables, then flatten the emissions from those into a single Observable`

Can someone give a good use case for it? Why transform the original Observable into Observables (plural) then turn them into a single Observable.

Why don't you just use 'map'?

If you give an example in Android that's awesome, otherwise plain Java is good enough. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's say you have an

```
Observable<Foo> fooObservable;
```

And you want to call another method which takes a `Foo` and emits an `Observable<Bar>`

Something like:

```
public Observable<Bar> getBars(Foo foo);
```

If you did:

```
fooObservable.map(foo -> getBars(foo));
```

You'd end up with an `Observable<Observable<Bar>>` because you've transformed your `Foo` -> `Observable<Bar>` which is probably not what you want.

Instead you can use `flatMap` which "flattens the observable":

```
Observable<Bar> barObservable = fooObservable.flatMap(foo -> getBars(foo));
```

Answer (score 28):

I see tag `Android` on your question. So, probably you should be familiar with `Retrofit`.

Let's image that you have 2 methods:

```
public interface FoxreyRestApi {

    @POST("/signin")
    Observable<SignInResponse> signin(@Body SignInRequest request);

    @GET("/user")
    Observable<User> getUser(String accessToken);
}
```

You want to get user data, but you need `accessToken`, which return is `SignInResponse`.

You can do this:

1). Create your `RestAdapter`.

2). Do queries one - after - another:

```
restAdapter.signin(request)
    .flatMap(r -> restAdapter.getUser(r.getAccessToken()))
    .subscribe(user -> {/*User your user*/});
```

Comment: thanks, your answer is an extremely useful answer in terms of Android and Retrofit. I marked @Will's answer below because it explained the concept of 'flat' spot on. Hope you don't mind. I've upvoted yours

Comment: @TungMaiLe,  thanks.  I just want to help you and make RxJava more popular,  because it's amazing. Will's answer is more detailed and i think your decision is absolutelly right

Comment: Great answer. That's how I understand flatmap too: it makes it possible to "chain" rxjava requests, one after another.

Answer (score 2):

Very often I use it to transform some of the UI events to observable background tasks:

```
ViewObservable.clicks(calculateBtn)
    .flatMap(new Func1<OnClickEvent, Observable<Integer>>() {
      @Override
      public Observable<Integer> call(OnClickEvent onClickEvent) {
          return observeBackgroundOperation()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())//interaction with UI must be performed on main thread
            .doOnError(new Action1<Throwable>() {//handle error before it will be suppressed
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    calculateBtn.setEnabled(true);
                    Toast.makeText(IOCombineSampleActivity.this, R.string.mix_error_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.<Integer>empty());//prevent observable from breaking
      }
    })
    .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {...});
```

Because it's easy to define background operations using observable, I used `flatMap` to transform button click events to 'something done in background events' (for example network request finished with Retrofit) and then observe them.

Note, that observable in `flatMap` can emit single value, which is done in sample.

This way I have declaratively defined interaction between UI and background processes.
I handle errors with `doOnError` and then use `onErrorResumeNext(Observable.<Integer>empty())` to prevent observable from terminating with `onError`. Because I use `flatMap`, my observable is not completed (while inner `flatMap` was) and is waiting for next click events.

Full sample of code you can find in [my article](http://blog.human-readable.net/2015/06/android-rxjava-combine-ui-io.html).